# Testing Hessian remoting-servlet.xml

Tags: java, testing, hessian

We are using Hessian for communication between a rich client and a server.

Due to moving and renaming it happens from time to time that the entries in the remoting-servlet.xml don't match the actual class names.

Therefor I'm looking for an easy way to test the remoting xml.

Is there an easy way to do that? Preferable without manually parsing the xml and trying to instantiate all classes mentioned in there.

Comment: Hessian's a bit of a dead duck these days. Is something more modern (and better supported) not an option?

Comment: Hessian is a dead duck? How comes? Works ok for us so far. Any alternatives you'd recommend?

Comment: I agree with Jens, Hessian is good choice.

Comment: @Ozhan: I disagree - it's no longer maintained, very few people use it, and there are better alternatives. @Jens: What are you using it for? What were the qualities of Hessian that you liked?

Comment: Ease of use with java (no code generation, coding directly against interfaces) and low bandwidth usage (although we never measured how important that is and I doubt it has much of an effect on our app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now create a Spring BeanFactory in a test:

```
private final BeanFactory factory =
        new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("remoting-servlet.xml"));
```

And try to create each configured bean:

```
assertNotNull(factory.getBean("beanName"));
```

Works nice