# If Hessian is Dead, what should one use instead?

Tags: rmi, hessian

In the comments to this question: [Testing Hessian remoting-servlet.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783411/testing-hessian-remoting-servlet-xml)

Skaffman labeled Hessian a dead duck. So question is: what to use as a replacement.

Criteria for evaluation are:

- a drop in replacement would be cool
- should allow simple coding against interfaces
- no code generation as a separate build step
- reasonable efficient considering network bandwidth
- not a dead duck

Important update:

- http based

Comment: What's wrong with vanilla RMI?  That matches all of those criteria.

Comment: RMI is used between java programs only. Not Hessian.

Comment: Maybe JSON would be the format to use today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use either Spring http invoker, hoping that the backing by the large spring ecosystem helps. It also looks like Hessian and http invoker should be easily exchangable.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look to Apache Commons? I think HttpClient and HttpRequest are great for many scenarios.

On the other hand, I recently talked to the great Douglas Schmidt about Hessian been outdated, he pointed out an important fact: after all, what really matters is if it works. I developed with Hessian and I love it!! I works like a charm. So I think I will keep working with it for a while.

Comment: I recently talked to Paul Cowan, a Caucho engineer, about how alive Hessian is. Hessian IS ALIVE, IS BEEN MAINTAINED, but not as a separate release, rather as part of Resin. So you can include resin.jar to work with the latest version of hessian.